# Parsing String to Date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a **`string`** `"Nov 6, 2017 11:47:53 AM"` to a **`Date`** through **`SimpleDateFormat`** but I'm not able to find the correct format to use. Someone can help me?

Comment: please show what you have tried, and what was the error/problem. The way you ask now you want somebody not to help you, but to do it instead of you.

Comment: please paste some code here to identify your problem.

Comment: A tip for you: You can find your answer faster by searching existing questions and answers than by waiting for someone to type a new answer here.

Comment: I recommend you consider [the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) rather than the outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. I know it’s not built-in on most Android phones yet, but you can get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and start using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template that should be able to parse this text is `MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a` assuming that the hours of the day are in the range of `1-12`. If they are in the range of `0-11` replace `hh` by `KK`.

Answer (score 1):

Use "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa"

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Date date = new Date();
        //Nov 6, 2017 11:47:53 AM
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa");
        //sdf.parse(source);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }

}
```

Output :

Nov 06, 2017 04:35:20 AM

Answer (score 0):

Even on Android it’s worth considering trashing the long outdated classes `Date` and in particular `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s shown to be quite troublesome. I recommend getting **ThreeTenABP**. It will allow you to use the modern Java date and time API on Android (that’s three-ten for JSR-310, where the API was first described).

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, uuuu h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String stringToParse = "Nov 6, 2017 11:47:53 AM";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringToParse, dtf);
```

The result is a `LocalDateTime` of `2017-11-06T11:47:53`.

If you absolutely need an old-fashioned `Date` object for some legacy API, you may do:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

There is much more about using ThreTenABP in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).